# How to solve error "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T' "?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry, int& size, int& capacity);

template <typename T>
T* allocate(int capacity);

template <typename T>
T* reallocate(T*new_list, T* list, const T& entry, int& size);

template <typename T>
void copy_list(T *dest, T* src, int many_to_copy);

template <typename T>
void print_list(T* list, int size);

template <typename T>
void Push_Back(T* list, int& size, T new_entry);

void test();


int main(){

   void test();

    return 0;
}


template <typename T>
T* add_entry(T* list, const T& new_entry, int& size, int& capacity){

    if (size == capacity)
        capacity *= 2;

    T* new_list = allocate(capacity);

    new_list = reallocate(new_list, list, new_entry, size);

       return new_list;
}



template <typename T>
T* reallocate(T*new_list, T* list, const T& entry, int& size){


        copy_list(new_list, list, size);
        Push_Back(new_list, size, entry);

        delete[] list;
    
    return new_list;
}

template <typename T>
T* allocate(int capacity){

    const bool debug = true;
    if (debug)
        cout<<"allocate: capacity: "<<capacity<<endl;

    return new T[capacity];

}

template <typename T>
void copy_list(T *dest, T* src, int many_to_copy){

    // processing the program until whole first array copy to second array
        for(int i = 0; i < many_to_copy; i++){

            // copy the element from first array to second array
            *dest = *src;
            // let the pointer point to the next element on the second array
            dest++;
            // let the pointer point to the next element on the first array
            src++;

        }

}

template <typename T>
void print_list(T* list, int size){

    // processing the program until print out whole array
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

          // output the element which the pointer point to
          cout<<*list<<" ";
          // let the pointer point to the next element on the array
          list++;

      }

}

template <typename T>
void Push_Back(T* list, int& size, T new_entry){

    list += size; // let the pointer point to the postion which after the
                // last element of array
     *list = new_entry; // add one element into where the pointer point
     size++; // increase 1 array size
}

template <typename T>
void test(){
    int capacity = 3;
        int size = 0;
        T* list = allocate(capacity);
        cout<<endl;
        list = add_entry(list, "Erika", size, capacity);
        print_list(list, size);
        cout<<endl<<"Size: "<<size;

        cout<<endl<<endl;

        list = add_entry(list, "Red", size, capacity);
        print_list(list, size);
        cout<<endl<<"Size: "<<size;

        cout<<endl<<endl;

        list = add_entry(list, "Bo", size, capacity);
        print_list(list, size);
        cout<<endl<<"Size: "<<size;
}
```

**Problem:**
In line

```
T* new_list = allocate(capacity);

T* list = allocate(capacity);
```

The complier says "**no matching function for call to 'allocate'**" and "**candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'**”. When I use "typedef string T;" instead of "template", the program will work. However, this is a school project, I am required to use "template".

**What I have tried:**

I tried to use "string* list = allocate(capacity) " and "string* list = allocate(capacity) " replace those two line of code. Then all add_entry function are not working.

How can I solve this problem, and why does it happen? Thanks for any help!

Comment: One can't deduce a T used only as return type. Only when it's used as an argument of the function

Comment: Even I change my return type to string, the problem still exist....

Answer (score 1):

you don't use T for return type, instead you can use auto, none of the methods whici you use in test method will don't work because you don't call correct, allocate is a template method and it need a return type

```
 auto* list = allocate<String>(capacity);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you said, and all my add_entry function are not working. the error is "no matching function for call to 'add_entry' " and "deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' for universal reference".  How can solve this?

Comment: same as for allocate you can specify return type for add_entry